# Sonatype Nexus using github for authentication/authorization

Tags: github, oauth, nexus

New to Nexus and I am trying to get it working with github for authentication/authorization.

I do have Nexus running and can successfully npm login, install, and publish following their docs using the default admin user.  Now, I am trying to secure my nexus npm repos with github auth.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

If you still have the problem, there is a plugin for nexus to do exactly that: https://github.com/larscheid-schmitzhermes/nexus3-github-oauth-plugin

Disclaimer: I am one of the authors of the plugin.